# Understanding and using did_action() in a conditional statement

Tags: actions, conditional-content, genesis-theme-framework

I'm working with Genesis Framework in a custom theme, but this is not a question "genesis-specific".

I need to populate the sidebar of my pages (not posts) conditionally.
The condition is to check that it is not already populated by many other related functions (related news, related events, ad banners selected by the user from the backend...).

The actions I need to verify that have not been fired are:
`genesis_after_sidebar_widget_area` and
`genesis_before_sidebar_widget_area`. I'm trying to get it through playing with `did_action()`.

I'm trying with this function:

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_sidebar_widget_area', 'understanding_did_action' );
function understanding_did_action() {
    if( did_action( 'genesis_after_sidebar_widget_area' ) > 0 || did_action( 'genesis_before_sidebar_widget_area' ) > 0 ) {
        echo '<h2>TESTING</h2>';
        echo 'before: ' . did_action( 'genesis_before_sidebar_widget_area' ) . '<br/>';
        echo 'after: ' . did_action( 'genesis_after_sidebar_widget_area' );
    }
}
```

and I always get: *before:* **1** & *after:* **1**, even in the cases that nothing is printed in the sidebar or the action has been fired two or three times.

The point is to find the way to execute the function only when the values are less than "X" (1, 2, 3... it will depend).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I may not be getting your fully, however do not you think that those actions always get called by the Genesis framework? I mean these are hook positions and they are always fired by genesis so that any functions tagged/hooked to those hooks will be called at those locations.. so it will always be 1 i.e. yes action hook was executed.

Comment: @Mohsin you put me on the right way. Indeed I was wrong trying to check the genesis hook doing it that way... I got it with "has_action" in spite of "did_action". Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Great! I have put the comment in the answer you make mark this question resolved! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those actions always get called by the Genesis framework. I mean these are hook positions and they are always fired by genesis so that any functions tagged/hooked to those hooks will be called at those locations.. so it will always be **1** i.e. yes action hook was executed.

As discovered rightly by OP, using `has_action` instead of `did_action` did the job.